# In Powershell, How to print only the list of parameters when no parameters are provided?

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, How to print only the command synax when no parameters are provided? Example:

```
PS> .\sign.ps1
sign.ps1 [-Trace] [-New] [-All] [[-File] <string[]>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Instead I get the complete Help page for the command... Here's what I'm doing.

```
# sign.ps1
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Script for Signing Powershell Scripts

.PARAMETER New
Create a new code signing certificate for signing powershell scripts.
(requires Powershell to be run in admin mode in order to make the certificate)


.PARAMETER File 
List of Powershell scripts to sign

.PARAMETER All
Sign all ps1 files in the current directory

.EXAMPLE
# Creates a new certificate stored in current direcctory as sign.pfx
PS> sign -New

# Sign all ps1 files in current directory
PS> sign -File *.ps1

#>
param(
    [switch]$Trace, 
    [switch]$New, 
    [switch]$All,
    [string[]]$File
)

if ($PSBoundParameters.Count -eq 0) {
    Get-Help $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
    exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To offer an alternative to [Jeff Zeitlin's effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71354098/45375):

[`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) `-Syntax` is designed to report a command's [syntax diagram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax), and it derives it directly from the target command's definition, not from its help. Therefore, it works whether or not the target command has (comment-based) help defined for it.

It is also useful in interactive use (e.g., `Get-Command -Syntax Get-ChildItem`, or, using aliases and elastic syntax, `gcm -sy gci`).

```
if ($PSBoundParameters.Count -eq 0) {
    Get-Command -Syntax $PSCommandPath
    exit 1
}
```

<sup>Note the use of the [automatic `$PSCommandPath` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pscommandpath) as a simpler way to refer to the running script's full path.</sup>

You can apply the technique to a *function* too:

```
if ($PSBoundParameters.Count -eq 0) {
    $MyInvocation.MyCommand | Get-Command -Syntax
    return
}
```

However, this isn't fully robust, because - unfortunately - `$MyInvocation.MyCommand`, which is an unambiguous [`System.Management.Automation.FunctionInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.FunctionInfo) instance, is *stringified* in the process, which means that `Get-Command` sees the only the function *name*, and not also its module context, so at least hypothetically `Get-Command` could act on a *different* function with the same name, from a different module / from the non-module scope domain.

This problematic `Get-Command` behavior - the inability to recognize [`System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo) instances (as well as of *derived* classes such as `FunctionInfo`) as such in its pipeline input - is the subject of [GitHub issue #11017](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11017).

If this were to get fixed, `$MyInvocation.MyCommand | Get-Command -Syntax` would work robustly in *both* scripts and functions.

Comment: This is fascinating, and told me something about `Get-Command` that I didn't know - that it had a `-Syntax` switch. :) Thanks for the info and the deep analysis.

Answer (score 3):

The output of the `Get-Help` command is an object which has several member properties. One of those properties is "syntax". Thus...

```
if ($PSBoundParameters.Count -eq 0) {
    (Get-Help $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).syntax
    exit 1
}
```

...should do the trick.

(*a little experimentation shows that this probably won't work for "built-in" commands, only for script cmdlets/advanced functions*)